# Nested Autowired Dependencies not injected in Junits

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Below is the code to demonstrate the issue. Class3 has autowired field Class2 and Class2 has autowired dependency of Class1, simpleTest to get the String value of Class1 using Class3. So in the test execution Class2 is not null and gets injected into Class3, but Class1 is null in Class2.

```
@Component
 class Class1{
 private String str= "Some String";
 //getter setter
}

@Component
class Class2{

@Autowired
Class1 class1;
//getter setter
}

@Component
class Class3{

@Autowired
Class2 class2;
 //getter setter
}

public class TestClass{

@InjectMocks
Class3 class3;

@Spy
Class2 class2;

@Spy
Class1 class2;

    @Test
    public void simpleTest(){
    
    String s = class3.class2.class1.getStr();
    Assert.equals(s,"Some String");
    
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works as you observed - `class2` is injected into `class3` due to `@InjectMocks` annotation, but `class1` is not injected into `class2`. Why don't you construct the objects manually? On top of that - do you use collaborators as spies?

Comment: Class1 in my case is actually the ObjectMapper object. I can construct the object manually, but will be a compromise just to make the unit test work.

Comment: If you want to use beans from spring context, you can certainly do so (you need `@Autowired` and `@SpringBootTest` or @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) with `@ ContextConfiguration`, and `@SpyBean` if you need spies). I'll refrain from recommending or disadvisiong this approach before seeing actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the `@Spy` annotation you put over the Class2, it makes the Class2 a mock and not a valid Spring bean.

If you want to get Spring's DI here, you'd have to get your beans with the `@Autowired` and maybe place

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

over your test to make it use the actual context.

Comment: Tried this but Class1 is still coming out as null

Comment: You can try creating a `@TestConfiguration` class with your classes declared as `@Beans` there...

Answer (score 0):

The below solved the problem.

```
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    Class2 class2;
```