# Nested Autowired Dependencies NOT Injected in JUnit 5 even with SpringExtension.class

Tags: java, spring, junit5

This question [Nested Autowired Dependencies not injected in Junits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542101/nested-autowired-dependencies-not-injected-in-junits) should have answered my question, but I'm already doing what it recommended. In fact, in Spring 5 with Java 11 and Junit 5, it was working. I'm not on Spring 6 and Java 17, but it's not.

This is effectively an integration test because it talks to the real database just to verify that I can get to the DB and that certain data items are as expected. The package it's a part of is excluded from normal test runs.

My test class looks something like this. Yes, I'm omitting most of the class, but the lines below are enough to expose the issue.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ExchangeDBTest {

    @Autowired public ExchangeCache exchangeCache;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createStdCloseData")
    void standardClose(LocalDate date, String exchangeCode, String stdTime, LocalTime time, TimeZone tz) {

        Exchange exchange = exchangeCache.get(exchangeCode);
        LocalDateTime stdClose = exchange.getStandardClose(date);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The ExchangeCache object is injected just fine. It's dependencies are injected just fine, which includes a DAO which does the retrieval and creation of the Exchange objects

```
@Service
public class ExchangeCacheImpl implements ExchangeCache, DataCache {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ExchangeCache.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("exchangeDAO")
    private ExchangeDAO exchangeDAO;
    
    ...
    
    private void loadAll() {
        /* Caller decides if this is a miss or not. */
        log.info("retrieving exchange data and calendars to populate cache...");
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        Collection<ExchangeData> batch = exchangeDAO.findAll();
        for (ExchangeData exData : batch) {
            if (exData.getMicCode() == null)
                continue;
            Exchange e = new ExchangeImpl();
            ...
    }
    ...
    }
```

The problem is with the construction of the ExchangeImpl objects which do not not have their dependencies injected *when I am running the JUnit test*. It works fine when deployed.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExchangeImpl implements Exchange, ExchangeCalendar {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("irregularHoursDAO")
    private ExchangeIrregularHoursDAO irregularHoursDAO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("regularHoursDAO")
    private ExchangeRegularHoursDAO regularHoursDAO;

    ...
}
```

Those two DAOs are null in the JUnit test, so that call to `exchange.getStandardClose(date)` throws an NullPointerException because the call triggers a DB query to get the missing data.

I found https://medium.com/davebarda/creating-a-dynamically-initialized-bean-in-spring-18d6d41d24df which suggested (among other things) a factory method to create the ExchangeImpl objects, so I tried

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public Exchange newExchangeImpl() {
       return new ExchangeImpl();
    }
    private void loadAll() {
        /* Caller decides if this is a miss or not. */
        log.info("retrieving exchange data and calendars to populate cache...");
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        Collection<ExchangeData> batch = exchangeDAO.findAll();
        for (ExchangeData exData : batch) {
            if (exData.getMicCode() == null)
                continue;
            Exchange e = newExchangeImpl();
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

but the objects returned still have null DAOs.

Again, it works when deployed, it's just the JUnit configuration I'm having a problem with. I'm reluctant to modify the actual ExchangeImpl too much and having it explicitly get the bean factory seems too much to me.

Comment: In short an `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if it is properly managed by Spring. In fact it would not even allow the application (or test) to start and fail with an exception stating that it cannot resolve the dependencies. Given that fact the `ExchangeImpl` instances you are using in your test aren't managed by Spring but are created outside the scope of the spring container. Not to mention that I find it weird that you have a DAO returning Spring managed components, why is it a DAO then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking. I thought the point of adding `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` was to get a spring container to manage everything.

Comment: No that is only letting the test class being managed by Spring. The instances you are creating for `ExchangeImpl` aren't managed by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this *is* the solution, along with calling this method instead of the constructor directly

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public Exchange newExchangeImpl() {
    return new ExchangeImpl();
}
```

but I was missing a `@Configuration` annotation on the class. Once I do that, the DAOs inside the Exchange object are initialized.